# Crashing when Calling CoUninitialize

Tags: c++, wmi

Based on [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I am creating `Windows Processing Monitoring` and `Windows Service Monitoring` DLLs that are to be called by the main application and run them in thread(using `boost::thread`) to get the data asynchronously. Consider that these both dll are run by my application. I get the error `Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x80010119` for one of my app. And also when stopping the threads for these dll, `CoUninitialize` is called in both of them. Here I get a crash. It might be because the `CoUninitialize` in latter thread might attempt to clear memory that was cleared by former thread.

If so, how can I check whether the `CoUninitialize` in one thread was successful so that I would not call it in another thread.

Comment: Is multiple initialization even allowed? Libraries should not do this, calling code should guarantee initialization as precondition. Also, the question has nothing tobwith WMI itself

Comment: I am using WMI API to get the data about Win32_Process and Win32_Service asynchronously. In the link I gave above, there is `CoInitializeEx` and `CoUninitialize`. Since I have created DLLs for these two task, Calling those two functions causes crash.

Answer (score 0):

CoUninitialize is a part of COM library, WMI can use COM interface, but has nothing to do with its initialization or disposal. Don't call CoUninitialize twice within one process. Note, that both of your DLL's probably share application context and are executed within it.

Comment: How do I handle the situation if **CoUninitialize** has been called twice? The thing is that both of my thread has **CoUninitialize** when thread exception occurs. It could be called twice from thread inside single process. Any clue?

Comment: These methods access application-wide scope and do not provide internal corrurent access protection. Only call Initialization and uninitialization once in main application thread or (not recommended) use an atomic boolean variable to protect from multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

"how can I check whether the `CoUninitialize` in one thread was successful so that I would not call it in another thread."

That tells me your error, but it's not in `CoUninitialize`. You are assuming that `CoUninitialize` is process-wide. In reality, `CoUninitialize` mirrors `CoInitializeEx`, and that should have de done on every thread. So your crash is almost certainly caused by a `CoInitializeEx` on one thread and the `CoUninitialize` on another thread.

The fix is to do `CoInitializeEx` on both threads, and `CoUninitialize` also on both threads.